UserManager.GetUserAsync returns a null
I have two projects. Project 1 is a VB project, and Project 2 is a .NET Core MVC project.
Project 1 sends data to Project 2. Based on the data that it receives, it creates a new identity user in the database and signs the user in. This all works as expected.
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateExternalUser(string externalJson)
{
    var externalTokenDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExternalTokenDetails>(externalJson);

    var company = _admin.GetCompanyByClientCode(externalTokenDetails.ClientCode);
    if (company != null)
    {
        var existingUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(externalTokenDetails.Email);
        if (existingUser != null)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, existingUser.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, existingUser.Email),
                new Claim("FullName", $"{externalTokenDetails.Name} {externalTokenDetails.Surname}"),
                new Claim("ClientCode", externalTokenDetails.ClientCode),
                new Claim("ClientName", externalTokenDetails.ClientName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, externalTokenDetails.RoleName),
            };

            var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
            var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, userPrincipal);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = externalTokenDetails.Email,
                Email = externalTokenDetails.Email,
                CompanyId = company.Id,
                Company = company,
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user); // Persist the user

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // User created successfully, sign them in
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                    new Claim("FullName", $"{externalTokenDetails.Name} {externalTokenDetails.Surname}"),
                    new Claim("ClientCode", externalTokenDetails.ClientCode),
                    new Claim("ClientName", externalTokenDetails.ClientName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, externalTokenDetails.RoleName),
                }; 
                
                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
                var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, userPrincipal);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}

The problem I am encountering is in my HomeController, Index method.
    System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
    bool isAdmin = currentUser.IsInRole("Admin");

           
    var id = _userManager.GetUserId(User); // Get user id:

    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

in this case after redirecting to this action, id and user is null
Why would this be and what other options do I have to get these values?

I solved it with the help of this question - JWT Authentication - UserManager.GetUserAsync returns null
By default getUserId and GetUserAsync looks at the NameIdentifier claim. I added this to my claims referencing the userId and it solved my issue.
